# Veracode Scan - Encapsulation flaw (Deserialization of Untrusted Data) in Java Springboot application

Tags: java, json, encapsulation, veracode

The Veracode scan reports one medium risk in a Springboot app code. It is a encapsulation flaw associated with Deserialization of Untrusted Data (CWE ID 502). I hope the experts here can help.

The searchReqStr is a JSON string from the request. The Vecacode is complaining on the objectMapper.readValue line.

```
 try {
  eventSearchFields = 
              objectMapper.readValue(searchReqStr,EventSearchFields.class);
          } catch (IOException e) {
                 ....
          }
```

The EventSearchFields class fields are all private

```
 public class EventSearchFields implements Serializable{

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 2373607xxxxx;       
   @JsonProperty("searchCriteria")
   private List<EventSearchCriteria> searchCriteria = new ArrayList<>();

   public List<EventSearchCriteria> getSearchCriteria() {
          return searchCriteria;
   }
   public void setSearchCriteria(List<EventSearchCriteria> searchCriteria) 
   {
          this.searchCriteria = searchCriteria;
   }   
 }
```

---

```
public class EventSearchCriteria implements Serializable{

  private static final long serialVersionUID = -624493860290016xxxxx;

  @JsonProperty("searchFieldName")
  private String searchFieldName;

  @JsonProperty("searchFieldValue")
  private transient List<?> searchFieldValue = new ArrayList<>();

  public String getSearchFieldName() {
  return searchFieldName;
  }
  public void setSearchFieldName(String searchFieldName) {
  this.searchFieldName = searchFieldName;
  }
  public List<?> getSearchFieldValue() {
 return new ArrayList<>(searchFieldValue);      
  }
  public void setSearchFieldValue(List<?> searchFieldValue) {
this.searchFieldValue = searchFieldValue;
```

### }

My guess is that I have a wild card “?” for searchFieldValue in EventSearchCriteria, because it can be a List if String or a List of Map, see sample request below. It is working perfectly, does that cause this Veracode scan issue ?

The search request json string

```
{
   "searchCriteria": [    

    {
     "searchFieldName":"keys",  
     "searchFieldValue":[    

           {   "searchFieldName":"bNumber", 
               "searchFieldValue":["11"]   
           }, 
           {
               "searchFieldName":"pNumber",
               "searchFieldValue":["22"]
            }, 
           {
               "searchFieldName":"id",
               "searchFieldValue":["BBB"]

           }             
      ]
               },
               {
     "searchFieldName":"unit",  
     "searchFieldValue":["aa","bb"] 
   }   
  ]
}
```

I have tried to change "?" to "Object" but no luck. Welcome suggestions to help me pass Veracode scan.

Comment: I think, `Veracode` complains because of deserialising data from `JSON` in general not because you use `?` or `Object` in `List` declaration. `Jackson` keeps you safe but you need to check your `ObjectMapper` configuration. Start from reading [On Jackson CVEs: Don’t Panic — Here is what you need to know](https://medium.com/@cowtowncoder/on-jackson-cves-dont-panic-here-is-what-you-need-to-know-54cd0d6e8062) and [Jackson 2.10 features](https://medium.com/@cowtowncoder/jackson-2-10-features-cd880674d8a2) articles.

Comment: @MichałZiober Thanks. I will check it out.